Cannot attach to browser to debug blazor WebAssembly when using TLS files
Edit: I've worked out that this is a problem relating to the use of subdomains under localhost. I tried using a custom domain with all the ceremony to get that working for a standard ASP.NET Core MVC website on my local machine, and now Blazor is also serving up pages that, for bonus points, are debuggable in the browser. I'll leave this question here because it's still disappointing that I cannot get this to work for, say, https://blazor.dev.localhost:8080.
(I also posted this issue in GitHub.)
I am able to debug code in the browser

with no TLS
when using a standard localhost (e.g. https://localhost:9891) while providing no TLS information.

If I provide my own localhost certificate, Blazor debugging does not work.
Expected Behavior:
When for a Blazor-hosted site I use the same TLS settings that work for a standard website, the server will host with TLS just as the ordinary website would, and debug just as is possible when using no TLS or std localhost TLS.
Steps To Reproduce:
Create a standard website so as to demonstrate that there are no errors involving TLS files.
launch.json:
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "straight web",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net8.0/StraightWeb.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+https?://\\S+",
        "uriFormat": "https://std-dotnet-web.dev.localhost:9891"
      },
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTPSINLINECERTANDKEYFILE__URL": "https://std-dotnet-web.dev.localhost:9891",
        "KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTPSINLINECERTANDKEYFILE__CERTIFICATE__PATH": "C:\\<path>\\localhost.crt",
        "KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTPSINLINECERTANDKEYFILE__CERTIFICATE__KEYPATH": "C:\\<path>\\localhost.key"
      },
    }
  ]
}

launchSettings.json:
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9891",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

Hit F5.
browser opens to https://std-dotnet-web.dev.localhost:9891/ and returns (via https) "Hello World!"
Now go to a Blazor-hosted website:
launch.json:
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch and Debug Hosted Blazor WebAssembly App",
      "type": "blazorwasm",
      "request": "launch",
      "hosted": true,
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorApp/BlazorApp/bin/Debug/net8.0/BlazorApp.dll",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTPSINLINECERTANDKEYFILE__URL": "https://my-cert.dev.localhost:9894",
        "KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTPSINLINECERTANDKEYFILE__CERTIFICATE__PATH": "C:\\<path>\\localhost.crt",
        "KESTREL__ENDPOINTS__HTTPSINLINECERTANDKEYFILE__CERTIFICATE__KEYPATH": "C:\\<path>\\localhost.key"
      },
      "browser": "edge",
      "url": "https://my-cert.dev.localhost:9894"
    }
  ]
}

launchSettings.json:
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
      }
    }
  }
}

Hit F5
Edge opens to about:blank, waits a while, but eventually returns a failure dialog "unable to launch browser" with a unreadable (incomplete) reference, such as ...:9894/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51495%2Fdev...
However a new tab can be opened and https://my-cert.dev.localhost:9894 is served up with no errors, but also no debugging. The counter increases but no stop is hit.
Now change launch.json:
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch and Debug Hosted Blazor WebAssembly App",
      "type": "blazorwasm",
      "request": "launch",
      "hosted": true,
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorApp/BlazorApp/bin/Debug/net8.0/BlazorApp.dll",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://*:9893",
      },
      "browser": "edge",
      "url": "https://localhost:9893"
    }
  ]
}

Hit F5. Edge opens to about:blank, waits a few seconds, the URL changes to https://localhost:9893 and debugging in the Counter page functions as expected, with stops honored.
Does anyone see anything obvious that I am doing incorrectly?
